# Performance : ArrayList or ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, game-engine, concurrenthashmap

I'm making a game, and I have to store some datas of sprites (e.g. position, Image etc) in a collection. And the question is which collection should I use?

I, My main problem is the collision detection:

1, First time I used a simple ArrayList, but when I have to check whether the actual sprite collide with other sprite I have to loop over all the other sprites to find out it. I thought its a bit too much of effort.

2, Second time I thought maybe ConcurrentHashMap would be the ideal. So when I try to move a sprite to an other place I can detect if it is a reserved place or not.

II, And then comes the other problem:

1, When I'm updating the ArrayList I can just loop over all the sprites and overwrite the old positions.

2, But when I'm updating the ConcurrentHashMap I have to remove the actual entry from the map and put a new instead of it (I can't just change the key, cause the value won't follow it). So here we got the performance problem with remove and put.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to make a special collection that sorts the elements in the background as time passes. Sorts them by their x value or something. Then when you are checking for collision, you are able to check only a subset of the list. Just a thought though :)

Comment: @Cruncher probably some kind of tree? It gets harder when it becomes 2D, but some kind of tree or connected graph with nodes that can see their neighbors could reduce the search time... or make it infinite, if the graph is implemented badly.

Comment: @AlexBeisley It's certainly a tricky implementation. But could definitely help if you need to cut a corner somewhere. I also fear, that sorting in the background won't give you much performance help, if it means context switching out your rendering process.

Comment: @Cruncher You should probably be rendering separately from processing this stuff anyway, with a list of all Drawable objects as references being fed to the renderer each iteration. Collision is always a pain though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unusual to me to base your collision on the collection type, unless that collection is a 2D/3D grid with one object per position, represented as an array. If it is, you can check a precise point on that array in O(1).

If you're doing collision precisely, in pixels or vectors, you probably will have to iterate.

I'd use a LinkedList of some kind in that case, because you'll probably be removing things on collisions.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a `LinkedList`, if the primary focus is iteration(and possibly removing during the iteration).

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking collision in pixels so I will iterate a lot.

Comment: Ah, in that case you'll want to look at my comments on your question, @Aksirba. You can definitely make some kind of virtual grid to restrict the objects you have to iterate through. You give your objects a cell, which gets updated based on the object's origin as it moves. If objects are a set size, you can know how many grid elements to get the objects within. However, if you have less than 50 items, you can get by with a list, most likely.

Comment: @Aksirba: Note that you either don't need `ConcurrentHashMap` or you can't use a `LinkedList`. Either you need concurrent access or not.